# How to structure uiview to display user comments similar to Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm curious about the best way to build the view to show user comments similar to Instagram.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDHGM.jpg

My best guess is that its a table view which loads each user comments from the backend. If so, how can I add the "click to more comments" functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you are right, you can use the scheme like this:

[image]
[image]

Of course you should correctly set:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

to return needed cell.
And when user clicks on **More Comments** button, just flag this, remove this row, and add new comment rows.